# convert VTK array to numpy array

Tags: vtk

I have a `VTKArray`

```
    [ 9841.628    7471.281    5349.856    3497.214    1919.413     609.9934
      -439.6396  -1233.646   -1770.145   -2040.984   -2075.757   -1984.518
     -1808.935   -1577.721   -1312.206   -1028.827    -740.5976   -458.0241
      -189.6907     57.3534    277.3451    465.6588    618.742     734.1347
       810.5912    848.3575    849.4676    817.9273    762.2106    693.2482
       620.0659    555.7937    518.7733    509.3184    514.604     526.1999
       538.6061    548.1713    552.5052    550.1421    540.3442    522.9915
       498.53      467.9678    432.9164    395.6847    359.4488    328.5395
       308.5232    302.2668    310.1853    330.2956    360.5213    400.5357
       450.2151    519.3795    609.7422    705.303     795.1875    872.1247
       931.1723    969.0032    983.4883    973.4471    938.5052    879.0258
       796.1007    691.5995    568.2879    430.0427    282.2285    131.8664
       -14.93232  -153.2414   -276.2176   -374.0019   -434.9348   -446.0255
      -404.1895   -327.7152   -231.296    -125.1121    -16.50685    89.09221
       187.6346    276.1179    352.3856    415.0075    463.2205    496.9212
       516.7113    524.0084    521.2542    512.2492    500.8893    490.9618
       487.1922    491.1486    500.7802    519.2238    558.1391    619.6867
       689.5275    757.3452    816.193     861.276     889.2769    897.961
       885.94      852.5322    797.6892    721.9731    626.5804    513.4172
       385.2427    245.9183    101.0781    -41.16037  -174.8881   -295.3871
      -392.2187   -451.6879   -466.8841   -429.2257   -346.5051   -236.1584
      -110.293      22.34385   155.2185    283.3487    402.9001    510.9344
       605.2533    684.3082    747.1624    793.5035    823.7121    839.0131
       841.7641    833.8945    813.3905    780.4894    736.8947    680.6016
       615.5346    561.8652    532.7382    517.0897    505.1629    490.7544
       469.8959    440.1411    400.1581    349.491     288.4247    217.919
       139.5959     55.77552   -30.43541  -114.9872   -192.63     -256.2448
      -293.3042   -290.6041   -239.5455   -133.7108     35.77769   272.1856
       566.9221    879.5015   1186.112    1472.166    1726.873    1941.9
      2110.604    2227.558    2288.249    2288.873    2226.199    2097.482
      1900.4      1633.028    1293.837     881.7343    396.4152   -159.6055
      -779.4574  -1448.777   -2145.205   -2839.88    -3489.114   -3966.019
     -4157.485   -4091.338   -3785.252   -3249.714   -2490.407   -1509.562
      -306.7563   1120.632    2777.175    4669.304    6805.346    9195.684
     11853.05   ]`
    `<class 'vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKArray'>
    <vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKNoneArray object at 0x0000016562C03730>
    <class 'vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKNoneArray'>
    <vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKNoneArray object at 0x0000016562C03730>
    <class 'vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKNoneArray'>
```

I’m trying to convert this to a numpy array

```
    from vtk.util import numpy_support
    
    education=py_data.PointData['fX_Lag']
        print(education)
        print(type(education))
        points = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(education)
    File "../DA_Blackbox\read_vtk_data.py", line 124, in read_vtk_Unstructured_Grid_Points_1
        points = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(education)
      File "D:\python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\util\numpy_support.py", line 215, in vtk_to_numpy
        typ = vtk_array.GetDataType()
    AttributeError: 'VTKNoneArray' object has no attribute 'GetDataType'
```

I hope to get a solution to convert this VTKArray into a numpy array.
Any help on how to resolve this error will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

`<class 'vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKArray'>` is already a subclass of numpy array. So no conversion needed, just use it.

[Some info](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/vtkNumPyIntegration.html#using-numpy-for-processing-data) about this `numpy_interface` module.